# How to make a ggplot timeseries plot from r dataframe using multiple columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe which I would like to to make an overlapping timeseries plot from, by ID, using four relevant data points for each ID. I don't know how to have all these show on top of each other. I want the lines to be divided into two colors, green for those which finish at a lower value than they began with and red for the opposite.

I don't know if I need to change my dataframe first or if I can do all the work with ggplot..

Here's a sample of my data (which has 38 total rows) All columns after ID should be points on the x axis and the Y should show from 0 to 3

```
      ID Starting_BAI HYP1_PostSession_1 HYP1_PostSession_4 HYP1_PostSession_8
 1     1            2                   1                   1                   0
 2     2            3                   3                   2                   1
 3     3            2                   2                   0                   0
 4     4            3                   3                   2                   0
 5     5            3                   2                   2                   1
 6     6            2                   2                   1                   1
 7     7            2                   2                   1                   0
 8     8            3                   3                   2                   1
 9     9            3                   3                   2                   0
10    10            3                   3                   1                   0
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a plot with 10 lines (1 for each ID), with x-axis being time (baseline and times 1, 4, and 8), and y-axis being the value (0-3), with the color indicating change from baseline (e.g., ID 1 starting with 2 ending with 0 would be green)...is that correct?

Comment: @Ben that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might rename your baseline value to `HYP1_Session_0` or something like that, so that the final number at the end indicates "time" and would be consistent with the other column names.

It will help to have your data into long form instead of wide (and tidy). This means each time observation for a particular ID is one row.

Using `pivot_longer`, your data can look like this in long form:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  rename(HYP1_Session_0 = Starting_BAI) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "time", values_to = "value", names_pattern = "(\\d+)$", names_transform = list(time = as.numeric))

# A tibble: 40 × 3
      ID  time value
   <int> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     0     2
 2     1     1     1
 3     1     4     1
 4     1     8     0
 5     2     0     3
 6     2     1     3
 7     2     4     2
 8     2     8     1
 9     3     0     2
10     3     1     2
# … with 30 more rows
```

After that, using `tidyverse` you can `group_by` your `ID` and add an indicator column `change` that will compare the values at time 0 and 8 (for coloring).

Finally, you can use `ggplot` to plot your spaghetti plot. Here we can indicate color based on `change`. In addition, `position_jitter` prevents lines from completely overlapping each other.

Note: I changed the data so that one of the `ID`s (ID #6) would result in a different color (red) - just for testing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  rename(HYP1_Session_0 = Starting_BAI) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "time", values_to = "value", names_pattern = "(\\d+)$", names_transform = list(time = as.numeric)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(change = value[time == 8] < value[time == 0]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = ID, color = change)) +
    geom_line(position=position_jitter(width = 0, height = .1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 4, 8)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
```

**Output**

[image: line plot time series]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Starting_BAI = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), HYP1_PostSession_1 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), HYP1_PostSession_4 = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), HYP1_PostSession_8 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```